Find equation of the form $ax+by=0$ for the line along the vector $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 3\\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right)$
Kindly vet:
As $ax+by$ is perpendicular to the line through the vector $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  a \\
  b \\
 \end{array} \right),$ so the equation of the line through the vector  is given by the vector perpendicular to it, i.e. $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  -b=-1 \\
  a=3 \\
 \end{array} \right);$  as the dot product of $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  a \\
  b \\
 \end{array} \right)\cdot \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  -b \\
  a \\
 \end{array} \right)= -ab+ba = 0.$
Hence, the equation of the required line is $-x + 3y=0.$

This is correct

Your work looks ok to me. $-x+3y=0$ passes through the origin and point $\begin{pmatrix}
3\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ so $-x+3y=0$ is a valid solution. Note that any equation of the form $c\cdot\left(-x+3y\right)=0$ for any arbitrary $c$ is also valid, e.g. $x-3y=0$.
